# привязать текст в div к переменной

Tags: javascript

есть список категорий который я получаю по апи ,при клике на эту категорию я должен получать ее название . Все категории это гиперссылки (по заданию) при клике на которые я должен отправлять запрос с названием этой категории и не перезагружать страницу. Допустим есть `<div id='items'> <a href=movie></a>movie</div>`

```
let currentCategory;
    let items = document.querySelectorAll("#items");
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
           let value= document.getElementById("#items");

           alert(value); 
            return false;

        });
```

в коде я отменяю перезагрузку при клике ,но как получить содержимое и записать его в переменную я не понимаю

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос, не совсем понятно что Вы имеете виду.

Comment: `id` - уникальный идентификатор, их не может быть несколько с одинаковым названием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить `id` на `class` и если вам нужно достать значение `movie` из `div`, то вам надо взять последнего потомка у вашего дива. Можете воспользоваться такой конструкцией `this.lastChild.data`

```js
let currentCategory;
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');
for (const item of items) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = this.lastChild.data;
    alert(value);
    currentCategory = value;
    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="items"> <a href="movie"></a>movie</div>
```